# Did Hillary Clinton support the Iraq war and trade agreements that have cost US jobs?

Tags: united-states, hillary-clinton

Bernie Sanders has been attacked repeatedly [by Hillary Clinton](https://mobile.twitter.com/HillaryClinton/status/717797172154998784) for his support of the 2005 Protection of Lawful Commerce in Arms Act. Sanders in an [interview with CBS News](http://www.politico.com/story/2016/04/bernie-sanders-iraq-hillary-clinton-221663) responded:

> Do I think the victims of a crime with a gun should be able to sue the manufacturer, is that your question?" Sanders responded.
>
> "No, I don't," Sanders said.
>
> “But maybe Secretary Clinton might want to apologize to the families who lost their loved ones in Iraq or Secretary Clinton might want to apologize to the millions of workers in this country who lost their jobs because of the disastrous trade agreements that she supported,” he continued.

**Did Hillary Clinton vote to go to war in Iraq?** (has she apologized?)

**Which trade agreements does Hillary support?**

Answer (score 10):

Hillary Clinton voted to authorize the Iraq war in [2002](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/war_stories/2016/02/hillary_clinton_told_the_truth_about_her_iraq_war_vote.html).

Hillary Clinton helped negotiate the basis for the [Trans-Pacific Partnership](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2016/feb/05/hillary-clinton/hillary-clintons-revisionist-history-tpp/) deal.

Hillary Clinton supported [NAFTA](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2008/feb/25/barack-obama/clinton-has-changed-on-nafta/) prior to her presidential campaign in 2008.

So yes, Hillary Clinton has a history of supporting both the Iraq war and trade agreements.

The "millions of jobs" is a political exaggeration.  Even strong advocates of that position put the number at [less than a million](http://www.epi.org/publication/fast-track-to-lost-jobs-free-trade-agreements-are-bad-deals-for-working-americans/).  Note that there have been extended periods of low unemployment after each trade agreement which suggests that regardless of magnitude, the economy's ability to create jobs outweighs the negative effects of trade agreements.  All this has been somewhat complicated by a long term trend away from manufacturing jobs in favor of automation.  And of course they don't measure additional jobs created by the monetary effects of low inflation.